# Simple syntax highlighter in Javascript - SQL highlighting

Tags: javascript, strings

Yesterday and today I've made a very basic syntax highlight.

It creates a function in the `window` object that handles part of the job:

```
(function(window){

    var f=window.highlight = function(lang, element){

        var lang_defs = f[lang];

        if(!lang_defs)
        {
            throw new TypeError( 'The language "' + lang + '" was not yet defined' );
        }

        if(!(element instanceof Element))
        {
            throw new TypeError( 'The 2nd parameter must be an Element' );
        }

        element.className += ' highlight ' + lang;

        for(var i = 0, l = lang_defs.length; i<l; i++)
        {
            var html = '';

            for(var j = 0, k = element.childNodes.length; j<k; j++)
            {
                if(element.childNodes[j].nodeType === 3)
                {
                    html += element.childNodes[j].nodeValue
                        .replace(
                            lang_defs[i].match,
                            /*shortcut to decide if the lang_defs[i].replace is one of those types
                             *if so, passes it directly
                             *otherwise, makes a string matching based on the object
                             */
                            {'string':1, 'function':1}[ typeof lang_defs[i].replace ]
                                ? lang_defs[i].replace
                                : '<' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag +
                                    ' class="' + lang_defs[i]['class'] + '">' +
                                        lang_defs[i].replace.text +
                                    '</' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag + '>'
                        );
                }
                else
                {
                    html += element.childNodes[j].outerHTML;
                }
            }
            element.innerHTML = html;

            if('function' === typeof lang_defs[i].patch)
            {
                var returned = lang_defs[i].patch.call( element );
                if('string' === typeof returned)
                {
                    element.innerHTML = returned;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //default replace object
    f.default_replace = {'tag': 'span', 'text': '$1'};

})(Function('return this')());//just be sure that we have the real window
```

Each language is a property in the function, which is then read (sql example):

```
(function(window){

    if('function' === typeof window.highlight)
    {
        window.highlight.sql=[
            {
                'class':'string',
                'match':/([bn]?"(?:[^"]|[\\"]")*"|[bn]?'(?:[^']|[\\']')*')(?=[\b\s\(\),;\$#\+\-\*\/]|$)/g,
                'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
            },
            {
                'class':'comment',
                'match':/((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/g,
                'replace':window.highlight.default_replace,
                'patch':function(){
                    return this.innerHTML.replace(
                            /((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/g,
                            '$1</span>'
                        ).replace(//matches single-line comments
                            /<span class="comment">((?:#|-- |\/\/)(?:.|<\/span><span class="[^"]+">([^<])<\/span>)*)([\r\n]|$)/g,
                            function(_,part1,part2,part3){
                                return '<span class="comment">'+
                                    //cleans up all spans
                                    ((part1||'')+(part2||'')).replace(/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/g,'')+
                                    '</span>'+
                                    (part3||'');
                            }
                        ).replace(//matches multi-line comments
                            /<span class="comment">(\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])+(?:\*\/(?:<\/span>)?|$))/g,
                            function(_,part1){
                                return '<span class="comment">'+
                                    //cleans up all spans
                                    ((part1||'')).replace(/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/g,'')+
                                    '</span>';
                            }
                        );
                }
            },
            {
                /*    
                 * numbers aren't that 'regular' and many edge-cases were left behind    
                 * with the help of @MLM (http://stackoverflow.com/users/796832/mlm),    
                 * we were able to make this work.    
                 * he took over the regex and patched it all up, I did the replace string    
                 */
                'match':/((?:^|\b|\(|\s|,))(?![a-z_]+)([+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE]-?\d+)?)((?=$|\b|\s|\(|\)|,|;))/g,
                'replace':'$1<span class="number">$2</span>$3'
            },
            {
                'class':'name',
                'match':/(`[^`]+`)/g,
                'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
            },
            {
                'class':'var',
                'match':/(@@?[a-z_][a-z_\d]*)/g,
                'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
            },
            {
                'class':'keyword',
                //the keyword replace must have an aditional check (`(?!\()` after the name), due to the function replace()
                'match':/\b(accessible|add|all|alter|analyze|and|as|asc|asensitive|before|between|bigint|binary|blob|both|by|call|cascade|case|change|char|character|check|collate|column|condition|constraint|continue|convert|create|cross|current_date|current_time|current_timestamp|current_user|cursor|database|databases|day_hour|day_microsecond|day_minute|day_second|dec|decimal|declare|default|delayed|delete|desc|describe|deterministic|distinct|distinctrow|div|double|drop|dual|each|else|elseif|enclosed|escaped|exists|exit|explain|false|fetch|float|float4|float8|for|force|foreign|from|fulltext|generated|get|grant|group|having|high_priority|hour_microsecond|hour_minute|hour_second|if|ignore|in|index|infile|inner|inout|insensitive|insert|int|int1|int2|int3|int4|int8|integer|interval|into|io_after_gtids|io_before_gtids|is|iterate|join|key|keys|kill|leading|leave|left|like|limit|linear|lines|load|localtime|localtimestamp|lock|long|longblob|longtext|loop|low_priority|master_bind|master_ssl_verify_server_cert|match|maxvalue|mediumblob|mediumint|mediumtext|middleint|minute_microsecond|minute_second|mod|modifies|natural|nonblocking|not|no_write_to_binlog|null|numeric|on|optimize|optimizer_costs|option|optionally|or|order|out|outer|outfile|parse_gcol_expr|partition|precision|primary|procedure|purge|range|read|reads|read_write|real|references|regexp|release|rename|repeat|replace(?!\()|require|resignal|restrict|return|revoke|right|rlike|schema|schemas|second_microsecond|select|sensitive|separator|set|show|signal|smallint|spatial|specific|sql|sqlexception|sqlstate|sqlwarning|sql_big_result|sql_calc_found_rows|sql_small_result|ssl|starting|stored|straight_join|table|terminated|then|tinyblob|tinyint|tinytext|to|trailing|trigger|true|undo|union|unique|unlock|unsigned|update|usage|use|using|utc_date|utc_time|utc_timestamp|values|varbinary|varchar|varcharacter|varying|virtual|when|where|while|with|write|xor|year_month|zerofill)\b/gi,
                'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
            },
            {
                'class':'func',
                'match':/\b([a-z_][a-z_\d]*)\b(?=\()/gi,
                'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
            },
            {
                'class':'name',
                'match':/\b([a-z\_][a-z_\d]*)\b/gi,
                'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
            }
        ];
    }

})(Function('return this')());
```

There are 2 themes: the default one and then a console-like one.

Example of the execution:

```js
// highlight function, separated file

(function(window){
 
 var f=window.highlight = function(lang, element){

  var lang_defs = f[lang];
  
  if(!lang_defs)
  {
   throw new TypeError( 'The language "' + lang + '" was not yet defined' );
  }
  
  if(!(element instanceof Element))
  {
   throw new TypeError( 'The 2nd parameter must be an Element' );
  }
  
  element.className += ' highlight ' + lang;
  
  for(var i = 0, l = lang_defs.length; i<l; i++)
  {
   var html = '';
   
   for(var j = 0, k = element.childNodes.length; j<k; j++)
   {
    if(element.childNodes[j].nodeType === 3)
    {
     html += element.childNodes[j].nodeValue
      .replace(
       lang_defs[i].match,
       /*shortcut to decide if the lang_defs[i].replace is one of those types
        *if so, passes it directly
        *otherwise, makes a string matching based on the object
        */
       {'string':1, 'function':1}[ typeof lang_defs[i].replace ]
        ? lang_defs[i].replace
        : '<' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag +
         ' class="' + lang_defs[i]['class'] + '">' +
          lang_defs[i].replace.text +
         '</' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag + '>'
      );
    }
    else
    {
     html += element.childNodes[j].outerHTML;
    }
   }
   element.innerHTML = html;
   
   if('function' === typeof lang_defs[i].patch)
   {
    var returned = lang_defs[i].patch.call( element );
    if('string' === typeof returned)
    {
     element.innerHTML = returned;
    }
   }
  }
 };

 //default replace object
 f.default_replace = {'tag': 'span', 'text': '$1'};

})(Function('return this')());//just be sure that we have the real window

//==========================================================

// sql syntax highlight, anothed different file

(function(window){

 if('function' === typeof window.highlight)
 {
  window.highlight.sql=[
   {
    'class':'string',
    'match':/([bn]?"(?:[^"]|[\\"]")*"|[bn]?'(?:[^']|[\\']')*')(?=[\b\s\(\),;\$#\+\-\*\/]|$)/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'comment',
    'match':/((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace,
    'patch':function(){
     return this.innerHTML.replace(
       /((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/g,
       '$1</span>'
      ).replace(//matches single-line comments
       /<span class="comment">((?:#|-- |\/\/)(?:.|<\/span><span class="[^"]+">([^<])<\/span>)*)([\r\n]|$)/g,
       function(_,part1,part2,part3){
        return '<span class="comment">'+
         //cleans up all spans
         ((part1||'')+(part2||'')).replace(/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/g,'')+
         '</span>'+
         (part3||'');
       }
      ).replace(//matches multi-line comments
       /<span class="comment">(\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])+(?:\*\/(?:<\/span>)?|$))/g,
       function(_,part1){
        return '<span class="comment">'+
         //cleans up all spans
         ((part1||'')).replace(/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/g,'')+
         '</span>';
       }
      );
    }
   },
   {
    /*    
     * numbers aren't that 'regular' and many edge-cases were left behind    
     * with the help of @MLM (http://stackoverflow.com/users/796832/mlm),    
     * we were able to make this work.    
     * he took over the regex and patched it all up, I did the replace string    
     */
    'match':/((?:^|\b|\(|\s|,))(?![a-z_]+)([+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE]-?\d+)?)((?=$|\b|\s|\(|\)|,|;))/g,
    'replace':'$1<span class="number">$2</span>$3'
   },
   {
    'class':'name',
    'match':/(`[^`]+`)/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'var',
    'match':/(@@?[a-z_][a-z_\d]*)/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'keyword',
    //the keyword replace must have an aditional check (`(?!\()` after the name), due to the function replace()
    'match':/\b(accessible|add|all|alter|analyze|and|as|asc|asensitive|before|between|bigint|binary|blob|both|by|call|cascade|case|change|char|character|check|collate|column|condition|constraint|continue|convert|create|cross|current_date|current_time|current_timestamp|current_user|cursor|database|databases|day_hour|day_microsecond|day_minute|day_second|dec|decimal|declare|default|delayed|delete|desc|describe|deterministic|distinct|distinctrow|div|double|drop|dual|each|else|elseif|enclosed|escaped|exists|exit|explain|false|fetch|float|float4|float8|for|force|foreign|from|fulltext|generated|get|grant|group|having|high_priority|hour_microsecond|hour_minute|hour_second|if|ignore|in|index|infile|inner|inout|insensitive|insert|int|int1|int2|int3|int4|int8|integer|interval|into|io_after_gtids|io_before_gtids|is|iterate|join|key|keys|kill|leading|leave|left|like|limit|linear|lines|load|localtime|localtimestamp|lock|long|longblob|longtext|loop|low_priority|master_bind|master_ssl_verify_server_cert|match|maxvalue|mediumblob|mediumint|mediumtext|middleint|minute_microsecond|minute_second|mod|modifies|natural|nonblocking|not|no_write_to_binlog|null|numeric|on|optimize|optimizer_costs|option|optionally|or|order|out|outer|outfile|parse_gcol_expr|partition|precision|primary|procedure|purge|range|read|reads|read_write|real|references|regexp|release|rename|repeat|replace(?!\()|require|resignal|restrict|return|revoke|right|rlike|schema|schemas|second_microsecond|select|sensitive|separator|set|show|signal|smallint|spatial|specific|sql|sqlexception|sqlstate|sqlwarning|sql_big_result|sql_calc_found_rows|sql_small_result|ssl|starting|stored|straight_join|table|terminated|then|tinyblob|tinyint|tinytext|to|trailing|trigger|true|undo|union|unique|unlock|unsigned|update|usage|use|using|utc_date|utc_time|utc_timestamp|values|varbinary|varchar|varcharacter|varying|virtual|when|where|while|with|write|xor|year_month|zerofill)\b/gi,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'func',
    'match':/\b([a-z_][a-z_\d]*)\b(?=\()/gi,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'name',
    'match':/\b([a-z\_][a-z_\d]*)\b/gi,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   }
  ];
 }

})(Function('return this')());

//=========================================================

// execution example:

window.onload = function(){
    
    highlight('sql', document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0]);
    
}
```

```css
/*console theme, main file*/

.highlight, .highlight *{
 background:black;
 color:white;
 font-family:'Consolas',monospace;
 font-size:16px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: pre;
}

/*sql style, different file*/

.highlight.sql .keyword{color:teal;}
.highlight.sql .string{color:red;}
.highlight.sql .func{color:purple;}
.highlight.sql .number{color:#0F0;}
.highlight.sql .name{color:olive;}
.highlight.sql .var{color:green;}
.highlight.sql .comment{color:gray;}
```

```html
<!-- example code, found somewhere on google, with some edge cases -->

<pre>
    
CREATE TABLE `shop` (
    article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
    dealer  CHAR(20)                 DEFAULT ''     NOT NULL,
    price   DOUBLE(16,2)             DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer));
INSERT INTO shop VALUES
    (1,'A',3.45),(1,'B',3.99),(2,'A',10.99),(3,'B',1.45),
    (3,'C',1.69),(3,'D',-1.25),(4,'D',19.95);
    
#This is an example of sql a = 'b', 'c'
    
SELECT MAX(article) AS article FROM shop;

SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.price &lt; s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
    
SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
FROM   shop
GROUP BY article;
    
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

SELECT @min_price:=MIN(price),@max_price:=MAX(price) FROM shop;
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE price=@min_price OR price=@max_price;
    
    /*
    
    a string =' ',
    
    */

select '1'#comment
    /*''*/ or 2;

</pre>
```

I'm actually happy with the results, but the comment highlighting is concerning me.

Is there anything I can do to improve the highlight syntax?
What can I do to improve the performance?
Am I handling comments correctly or should I try a different way?

Comment: [Recent, related question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/90351/14370)

Comment: @Flambino I know. I commented there. And that was my main inspiration.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that now. Well, now the link's there in case anyone else is interested.

Comment: @Flambino Thanks a lot for the link. I should have refered that in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After closely watching the code, I realized that I've made a few mistakes:

**Mistake 1:**

The languages are being added *directly* as a property in the function. That's just begging for trouble!

I've added an object where all the languages will be added.

**Mistake 2:**

To generate the new HTML to search for the text nodes (the un-highlighted text), I was refreshing the element itself.

That means that all the styles related with that element were being refreshed over and over and over again.

Now, with a document fragment, the number of reflows was reduced to 2!

**Mistake 3 (or 2.5?):**

Since I was setting the class at the beggining, before any code, which was helping in the number of reflows.

This is a total waste of time for the CPU. This reflow was moved before doing any direct changes in the code, but before adding the new HTML.

**Mistake 4:**

The lack of 'stricness' disturbed some people.

And it is a good point!

Now, `'use strict';` is present in the code.

---

Now, with all the mistakes sorted out, I've also made some changes:

**Change 1:**

The language now can be set directly in the element, or as an optional parameter in the function.

**Change 2:**

If you forget to set a language, both on the element and in the parameter, it throws a friendly exception.

Also, the exception about the language being missing was adjusted.

**Change 3:**

You can now pass a set of elements (`NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`) and the elements will be highlighted.

The exceptions that are thrown will be handled differently, giving the other elements a chance.

The individual results for each element are returned in the form of an array.

**Change 4:**

[@Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast) pointed out something very simple and small.

The initialization had the following line:

```
var f=window.highlight = function(element, lang){//...
```

At first, it is completely unclear what `f` is doing.

I've changed it's name to `fn`, and added a description of what that variable is doing there.

---

After all the changes, this is the final result:

```js
(function(window){

    'use strict';

    //fn keeps an internal reference to avoid problems with rewritting the window.highlight
    var fn = window.highlight = function(element, lang){

        'use strict';

        if(element instanceof NodeList || element instanceof HTMLCollection)
        {
            for(var i = 0, l = element.length, results = []; i<l; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    results[i] = fn( element[i], lang );
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    //logs the message, to give a chance to all the other elements
                    ( console.error || console.log ).call( console, e.message );

                    results[i] = false;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        if(!(element instanceof Element))
        {
            throw new TypeError( 'The 1st parameter must be an Element or NodeList' );
        }

        lang = lang || element.getAttribute('data-lang');

        if(!lang)
        {
            throw new TypeError( 'Missing language definition. Set the 2nd parameter or the attribute data-lang' );
        }

        var lang_defs = fn.langs[lang];

        if(!lang_defs)
        {
            throw new TypeError( 'The language "' + lang + '" was not yet defined' );
        }

        //create a document fragment, to avoid reflow and increase performance
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            div = document.createElement('div');

        div.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        fragment.appendChild(div);

        for(var i = 0, l = lang_defs.length; i<l; i++)
        {
            var html = '';

            for(var j = 0, k = div.childNodes.length; j<k; j++)
            {
                if(div.childNodes[j].nodeType === 3)
                {
                    html += div.childNodes[j].nodeValue
                        .replace(
                            lang_defs[i].match,
                            /*shortcut to decide if the lang_defs[i].replace is one of those types
                             *if so, passes it directly
                             *otherwise, makes a string matching based on the object
                             */
                            {'string':1, 'function':1}[ typeof lang_defs[i].replace ]
                                ? lang_defs[i].replace
                                : '<' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag +
                                    ' class="' + lang_defs[i]['class'] + '">' +
                                        lang_defs[i].replace.text +
                                    '</' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag + '>'
                        );
                }
                else
                {
                    html += div.childNodes[j].outerHTML;
                }
            }

            //refreshes the HTML, before doing anything else
            div.innerHTML = html;

            if('function' === typeof lang_defs[i].patch)
            {
                var returned = lang_defs[i].patch.call( div );
                if('string' === typeof returned)
                {
                    div.innerHTML = returned;
                }
            }
        }


        //only change at the end, to avoid unnecessary reflows
        element.className += ' highlight ' + lang;
        element.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;

        return true;
    };

    //default replace object
    fn.default_replace = {'tag': 'span', 'text': '$1'};

    //all the languages will be added here
    fn.langs = {};

})(Function('return this')());//just be sure that we have the real window
```

---

Example of an execution (same HTML and CSS):

```js
//main file, containing the main function

(function(window){
 
 'use strict';
 
 //fn keeps an internal reference to avoid problems with rewritting the window.highlight
 var fn = window.highlight = function(element, lang){
  
  'use strict';
    
  if(element instanceof NodeList || element instanceof HTMLCollection)
  {
   for(var i = 0, l = element.length, results = []; i<l; i++)
   {
    try
    {
     results[i] = fn( element[i], lang );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
     //logs the message, to give a chance to all the other elements
     ( console.error || console.log ).call( console, e.message );

     results[i] = false;
    }
   }
   return results;
  }
  
  if(!(element instanceof Element))
  {
   throw new TypeError( 'The 1st parameter must be an Element or NodeList' );
  }
  
  lang = lang || element.getAttribute('data-lang');
  
  if(!lang)
  {
   throw new TypeError( 'Missing language definition. Set the 2nd parameter or the attribute data-lang' );
  }
  
  var lang_defs = fn.langs[lang];
  
  if(!lang_defs)
  {
   throw new TypeError( 'The language "' + lang + '" was not yet defined' );
  }
  
  //create a document fragment, to avoid reflow and increase performance
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
   div = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
  fragment.appendChild(div);
  
  for(var i = 0, l = lang_defs.length; i<l; i++)
  {
   var html = '';
   
   for(var j = 0, k = div.childNodes.length; j<k; j++)
   {
    if(div.childNodes[j].nodeType === 3)
    {
     html += div.childNodes[j].nodeValue
      .replace(
       lang_defs[i].match,
       /*shortcut to decide if the lang_defs[i].replace is one of those types
        *if so, passes it directly
        *otherwise, makes a string matching based on the object
        */
       {'string':1, 'function':1}[ typeof lang_defs[i].replace ]
        ? lang_defs[i].replace
        : '<' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag +
         ' class="' + lang_defs[i]['class'] + '">' +
          lang_defs[i].replace.text +
         '</' + lang_defs[i].replace.tag + '>'
      );
    }
    else
    {
     html += div.childNodes[j].outerHTML;
    }
   }
   
   //refreshes the HTML, before doing anything else
   div.innerHTML = html;
   
   if('function' === typeof lang_defs[i].patch)
   {
    var returned = lang_defs[i].patch.call( div );
    if('string' === typeof returned)
    {
     div.innerHTML = returned;
    }
   }
  }
  
  
  //only change at the end, to avoid unnecessary reflows
  element.className += ' highlight ' + lang;
  element.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
  
  return true;
 };

 //default replace object
 fn.default_replace = {'tag': 'span', 'text': '$1'};
 
 //all the languages will be added here
 fn.langs = {};

})(Function('return this')());//just be sure that we have the real window


//==========================================================

// sql syntax highlight, anothed different file

(function(window){
 'use strict';
 if('function' === typeof window.highlight)
 {
  window.highlight.langs.sql=[
   {
    'class':'string',
    'match':/([bn]?"(?:[^"]|[\\"]")*"|[bn]?'(?:[^']|[\\']')*')(?=[\b\s\(\),;\$#\+\-\*\/]|$)/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'comment',
    'match':/((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace,
    'patch':function(){
     'use strict';
     return this.innerHTML.replace(
       /((?:\/\/|\-\-\s|#)[^\r\n]*|\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])*(?:\*\/|$))/g,
       '$1</span>'
      ).replace(//matches single-line comments
       /<span class="comment">((?:#|-- |\/\/)(?:.|<\/span><span class="[^"]+">([^<])<\/span>)*)([\r\n]|$)/g,
       function(_,part1,part2,part3){
        return '<span class="comment">'+
         //cleans up all spans
         ((part1||'')+(part2||'')).replace(/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/g,'')+
         '</span>'+
         (part3||'');
       }
      ).replace(//matches multi-line comments
       /<span class="comment">(\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^\/])+(?:\*\/(?:<\/span>)?|$))/g,
       function(_,part1){
        return '<span class="comment">'+
         //cleans up all spans
         ((part1||'')).replace(/<\/?span(?: class="[^"]+")?>/g,'')+
         '</span>';
       }
      );
    }
   },
   {
    /*    
     * numbers aren't that 'regular' and many edge-cases were left behind    
     * with the help of @MLM (http://stackoverflow.com/users/796832/mlm),    
     * we were able to make this work.    
     * he took over the regex and patched it all up, I did the replace string    
     */
    'match':/((?:^|\b|\(|\s|,))(?![a-z_]+)([+\-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE]-?\d+)?)((?=$|\b|\s|\(|\)|,|;))/g,
    'replace':'$1<span class="number">$2</span>$3'
   },
   {
    'class':'name',
    'match':/(`[^`]+`)/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'var',
    'match':/(@@?[a-z_][a-z_\d]*)/g,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'keyword',
    //the keyword replace must have an aditional check (`(?!\()` after the name), due to the function replace()
    'match':/\b(accessible|add|all|alter|analyze|and|as|asc|asensitive|before|between|bigint|binary|blob|both|by|call|cascade|case|change|char|character|check|collate|column|condition|constraint|continue|convert|create|cross|current_date|current_time|current_timestamp|current_user|cursor|database|databases|day_hour|day_microsecond|day_minute|day_second|dec|decimal|declare|default|delayed|delete|desc|describe|deterministic|distinct|distinctrow|div|double|drop|dual|each|else|elseif|enclosed|escaped|exists|exit|explain|false|fetch|float|float4|float8|for|force|foreign|from|fulltext|generated|get|grant|group|having|high_priority|hour_microsecond|hour_minute|hour_second|if|ignore|in|index|infile|inner|inout|insensitive|insert|int|int1|int2|int3|int4|int8|integer|interval|into|io_after_gtids|io_before_gtids|is|iterate|join|key|keys|kill|leading|leave|left|like|limit|linear|lines|load|localtime|localtimestamp|lock|long|longblob|longtext|loop|low_priority|master_bind|master_ssl_verify_server_cert|match|maxvalue|mediumblob|mediumint|mediumtext|middleint|minute_microsecond|minute_second|mod|modifies|natural|nonblocking|not|no_write_to_binlog|null|numeric|on|optimize|optimizer_costs|option|optionally|or|order|out|outer|outfile|parse_gcol_expr|partition|precision|primary|procedure|purge|range|read|reads|read_write|real|references|regexp|release|rename|repeat|replace(?!\()|require|resignal|restrict|return|revoke|right|rlike|schema|schemas|second_microsecond|select|sensitive|separator|set|show|signal|smallint|spatial|specific|sql|sqlexception|sqlstate|sqlwarning|sql_big_result|sql_calc_found_rows|sql_small_result|ssl|starting|stored|straight_join|table|terminated|then|tinyblob|tinyint|tinytext|to|trailing|trigger|true|undo|union|unique|unlock|unsigned|update|usage|use|using|utc_date|utc_time|utc_timestamp|values|varbinary|varchar|varcharacter|varying|virtual|when|where|while|with|write|xor|year_month|zerofill)\b/gi,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'func',
    'match':/\b([a-z_][a-z_\d]*)\b(?=\()/gi,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   },
   {
    'class':'name',
    'match':/\b([a-z\_][a-z_\d]*)\b/gi,
    'replace':window.highlight.default_replace
   }
  ];
 }

})(Function('return this')());

//=========================================================

// execution example:

window.onload = function(){
 
 highlight(document.getElementsByTagName('pre'));
 
}
```

```css
/*styling for this example only*/


p {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
pre {margin-top:5px;}

/*console theme, main file*/

.highlight, .highlight *{
 background:black;
 color:white;
 font-family:'Consolas',monospace;
 font-size:16px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: pre;
}

/*sql style, different file*/

.highlight.sql .keyword{color:teal;}
.highlight.sql .string{color:red;}
.highlight.sql .func{color:purple;}
.highlight.sql .number{color:#0F0;}
.highlight.sql .name{color:olive;}
.highlight.sql .var{color:green;}
.highlight.sql .comment{color:gray;}
```

```html
<p>Simple example:</p>

<pre data-lang="sql">

insert into `table` select * from `_copy` where id &lt; 55;

</pre>

<p>Simple example, without language defined:</p>

<pre>

select "This will be 'unhighlighted'";

</pre>

<p>Complex example:</p>

<pre data-lang="sql">
    
CREATE TABLE `shop` (
    article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
    dealer  CHAR(20)                 DEFAULT ''     NOT NULL,
    price   DOUBLE(16,2)             DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer));
INSERT INTO shop VALUES
    (1,'A',3.45),(1,'B',3.99),(2,'A',10.99),(3,'B',1.45),
    (3,'C',1.69),(3,'D',-1.25),(4,'D',19.95);
    
#This is an example of sql a = 'b', 'c'
    
SELECT MAX(article) AS article FROM shop;

SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.price &lt; s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
    
SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
FROM   shop
GROUP BY article;
    
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);

SELECT @min_price:=MIN(price),@max_price:=MAX(price) FROM shop;
SELECT * FROM shop WHERE price=@min_price OR price=@max_price;
    
    /*
    
    a string =' ',
    
    */

select '1'#comment
    /*''*/ or 2;

select "Also has support for "" &lt;-- that style of quotes",
       '''Like this as well!''';

</pre>
```

Comment: `var f=window.highlight` In your opinion, is `f` a descriptive name for such a `var`?

Comment: @Mast Not really. `f` is a local variable, used to refer internally to the function `window.highlight`. This is just to avoid repeating `window.highlight.<property>` every single time, and also to avoid that, when someone does something similar to this: `var x=window.highlight;window.highlight=null;`, it will still work correctly (the language replace rules are bound to the `window.highlight`, but it is easily changeable). Probably naming `fn` or something would be better. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not up to date with naming conventions in JS, but `tWindowVar` would be more descriptive than `f`. Still not great, but better. If you're concerned about safety, you might be interested in [strict](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/javascript-strict-mode/).

Comment: @Mast It's not safety. It's just so that people don't screw up. Relying as little as possible in the outside. Imagine the chaos that would be if someone just ran `window.highlight=null;` while I was accessing directly to `window.highlight` within the function. `tWindowVar` would be fine in VB, but in Javascript, it wouldn't be that good. Also, what for is the `t` there? And why `WindowVar`? It is a local variable, so, it won't be exposed to the `window` object. But yes, I should be using `'use strict';`. I will add it there. I will change `f`  to `fn` (`fn` is short for `function`).

Comment: @Mast Sorry the delay to say something. I've made some changes in the answer and changed the name to `fn`, like I said I would do. Thanks for reminding me of the strict mode, I totally forgot about it.

Comment: No problem, looks good now :)